# Having Exception handling as a common method in Ruby

Tags: ruby, exception

Can someone tell me is there a way to make the exception handling as a common method and use it inside a methods? Let me explain it further.

For example, I have following methods

```
def add(num1, num2)
 begin
   num1 + num2
 rescue Exception => e
   raise e
 end 
end

def divide(num1, num2)
 begin
   num1 / num2
 rescue Exception => e
   raise e
 end 
end
```

As you can see, even though my method needs only one line, because of the exception handling code, the method gets bigger.

What I'm looking for is a more slimmer solution like (just a thought)

```
def add(num1, num2)
  num1 + num2 unless raise_exception
end

def divide(num1, num2)
 num1 / num2 unless raise_exception
end  

def raise_exception
  raise self.Exception
end
```

Please note the above code doesn't work, just my idea. Is this possible or is there any other good way?

Comment: Note that you can also cut down on the verbosity by eliminating the `begin..end`, as you can have a `rescue` within a `def..end` with the same effect.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
def handle_exception(&block)
  yield
rescue Exception => e
  raise e
end

def add(num1, num2)
  handle_exception { num1 + num2 }
end

def divide(num1, num2)
  handle_exception { num1 / num2 }
end
```

Comment: One potential downside to consider is that all errors raised would point to the same line number

Comment: True, but this is also a contrived example. If you were just re-raising the error, you wouldn't bother catching it in the first place. This would be useful if you have some common error-handling code.

Answer (score 6):

yep, something like that:

```
 def try
    yield
  rescue Exception => e
    puts 'I`m rescued'
  end

  def devide(num1, num2)
   try { num1/num2 }
  end

ruby-1.9.2-p180 :013 > devide(5,1)
 => 5 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :014 > devide(5,0)
I`m rescued
 => nil
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I had to accept david's answer as he has given the answer first, sorry.. but thanks again, this is the one I wanted...

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you could pass a block in to a method that yields inside the begin section.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, could u direct me to an example usage of block and yield code sample, thanks again

Comment: It'd be just as quick for you to google as having me do it :)

Comment: @MWiesner Actually it does; it's an expurgated version of the top two answers.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you rescue an Exception and raise it afterwords?
Your calling routine must rescue again your exception.

You could do:

```
def divide(num1, num2)
   num1 / num2
end 

begin
  divide(1,0) 
rescue Exception => e
  puts "Exception '#{e}' occured"
end
```

You may rescue the Exception in one line:

```
def divide2(num1, num2)
  num1 / num2 rescue Exception 
end 

 p divide2(6,3) # -> 2
 p divide2(1,0) # -> Exception
```

But then you will loose the information which Exception occured.